# resizing social links with media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am having some difficulties. I am developing a website and am having issues with the social link icons going tiny when the screen size is reduced. I'd like to use media queries to specify the size for smaller screens - what I am trying is not working.

Social links at top of page:

```
 `<div class="container">
    <div class="row-1">
        <!--First column-->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="images/fbGrey.png" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:50px" alt="Find us on Facebook">
                <hr class="vertical"/>

        </div>
<!--Second column-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="images/twitterGrey.png" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:50px" alt="Follow us on Twitter">
        <hr class="vertical"/>

        </div>
<!--Third column-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="images/instagramGrey.png" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:50px" alt="Follow us on Instagram">
        <hr class="vertical"/>

        </div>
<!--Fourth column-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="images/pinterestGrey.png" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:50px" alt="Follow us on Pinterest">
        <hr class="vertical"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Social links in footer:
      `

```
        <!--First column-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
 <!--Social buttons-->
        <!--First column-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-3">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="images/fbGrey.png" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:70px" alt="Find us on Facebook" id="fb">
    <img src="images/twitterGrey.png" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:70px" alt="Follow us on Twitter">

    <img src="images/instagramGrey.png" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:70px" alt="Follow us on Instagram">

    <img src="images/pinterestGrey.png" class="img-responsive" 
style="width:70px" alt="Follow us on Pinterest">

    </div>
</div>
</div>`
```

Additionally, within the footer the height of `<div class="footer-copyright">`
 increases when the screen size is reduced - anybody know why this is happening? I would also like to use media queries to fix this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 `<!--footer-->
  <div class="span4">
    <!-- empty, but using spacer to prevent collapse -->
     <div class="spacer10"></div>
    </div>            </div>

        <!--Second column-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5 class="title">OUR SERVICES</h5>
                <p><a href="treatments.html">Treatments</a></p>
                <p><a href="bookings.html">Bookings</a></p>
                <p><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></p>
            </div>

        <!--First column-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5 class="title">COMPANY</h5>
                <p><a href=index.html>Home</a></p>
                <p><a href="contact.html">Location</a></p>
                <p><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></p>
                <p><a href="privacypolicy.html">Privacy Policy</a></p>

        </div>
            <!--Second column-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5 class="title">CONTACT</h5>
                <strong>Hands on Sports & Holistic Therapy</strong><br>
                50 Westonfields<br>
                Bridgetown<br>
                Totnes<br>
                TQ90 5QX<br>
                <abbr title="Phone">P: 07450232531</abbr><br><br>
            </address>

            <address>
                <strong>Email: </strong><br>
                <a href="mailto:#">jo@handson-therapy.com</a>
            </address>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>
 <!--Copyright-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row-5">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <center>© 2017 Copyright: Hands on Sports & Holistic 
Therapy. All rights reserved.</center>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span4">
    <!-- empty, but using spacer to prevent collapse -->
     <div class="spacer40"></div>
    </div>

</footer>
<!--/.Footer-->`
```

Here is my code in JSFiddle - obvs no images present.
https://jsfiddle.net/AnnieWebDev/frrvmpnr/

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There is no link to your jsfiddle. Please also include the code in the question.

Comment: Wow that was fast - realised as soon as I posted and added the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to set min-width: 70px !important; on the img tag. This way the image will not go any smaller than the value which you set in there.

Comment: are they supposed to be in a list or across the page. as i think setting col-xs-3 is for smaller screens size's as col-sm-3 looks like it stretches the entire width

Comment: They are supposed to be in a list within the footer, and horizontal at the top of the page. So which should I use? "xs, sm, md, lg" ? They scale up - so should I be using xs?

Comment: Usually all are used on the same column so they change depending on the size of the screen. You should have a closer look at bootstrap for this as they explain this in their documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Have now fixed the issue with the social icons, I removed the value from `row` and put all the icons in an extra column and used the offset to keep them to the right on large and medium screens. I could not get the offset to work previously - hence the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code. Enter your code here and hit check and then fix the errors. [html validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)

Take `</link>` off the end of the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>`

`<center>` is obscolete, use css. In your css style sheet you can add  `h1 {
    text-align: center;}` or inline html do it like this  `<h1 style="text-align:center;">Centered Heading</h1>`

Comment: Thank you - I've made these changes and others that were suggested. Still having issues though :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your `head` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks - doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Is your test page live anywhere? Post a link to it, or update your JS Fiddle and post that link again.

Comment: Annie in the html you don't have <head> but you do have the closing </head>. Put it right under <!doctype html> Then on all of your image lines take out the \ and use /